# SQL Script If statement

Tags: sql, if-statement

Please assist with the below sql query. I’m trying to run the query below but not sure what to do. Thanks in advance

```
If ALT < 40090 or TPS > 23 or ABS > 0.399 then 1 else 0
```

Comment: A query starts with `SELECT`, not `IF`.

Answer (score 0):

An `IF` *statement* is a flow control structure that is generally meant to be used in a stored procedure or the-like.

If you want to put that in a query, then you presumably, you want a `case` *expression*:

```
case when ALT < 40090 or TPS > 23 or ABS > 0.399 then 1 else 0 end
```

You can put such expression in a query:

```
select
    case when ALT < 40090 or TPS > 23 or ABS > 0.399 then 1 else 0 end as res
    -- other columns
from ...
```